# Searchbox for Windows form application c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have implemented a searchbox for a gridview in a windows form C# application. It currently works but only searches one column. This is where columns[1] is. Can someone please help me search all columns in th gridview I currently have 15 columns:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
    bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + txt_search.Text + "%'";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

Comment: Is the GridView Datasource a Datatable or DataSet?

Comment: yes, but what is the original Datasouce of the data Grid view? is it a DataTable ?

Comment: I apologize, I went to the toolbox, dragged a datagridview onto the canvas and configured my datasource with the gui which is an sql database. Does this help?

Comment: So you just want to search the HeaderText then? If a column has the header text, display that column correct?

Comment: I want to search the entire gridview for matching text simliar to Ctrl F in microsoft excel

Comment: I feel like you would be better off searching SQL rather than the Grid, so you could search sql, then rebind the Grid with the new results.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial on how to acomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

[String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) works well here.

```
bs.Filter = string.Format("COLUMN1 LIKE '%{0}%' OR COLUMN2 LIKE '%{0}%'", txt_search.Text);
```

You should match on the **Name** property of the [DataGridViewColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of **HeaderText**, as header text is the display caption and need not match the underlying column name.

You can always iterate the columns to build your filter:

```
string filter = string.Empty;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (column.Index == 0) 
    {
        filter += string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", column.Name, txt_search.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        filter += string.Format(" OR {0} LIKE '%{1}%'", column.Name, txt_search.Text);
    }
}

bs.Filter = filter;
```